# Select values which are distinct in a group but not overall

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below:

```
    id  title  year
    ---------------
    1    abc   1999
    2    abc   2000
    3    abc   2000
    4    abc   1998
    5    bce   1999
    6    bce   1999
    7    def   1999
    8    def   1999
    9    def   2000
```

I need to get a list of titles which are distinct for a year but otherwise they can repeat. Tried distinct but it is giving distinct overall not based on year.

Tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT `title` FROM xyz WHERE year IN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM xyz)
```

Current output:

```
   abc
   bce
   def
```

Expected output:

```
   abc
   abc
   abc
   bce
   def
   def
```

Comment: So you don't care to know which title corresponds with which year?

Comment: no @Strawberry it is not required

Comment: Well, mysql allows this rather strange syntax (other RDBMSs prohibit it)... `SELECT title FROM xyz GROUP BY year,title ORDER BY title;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `title`
FROM `xyz`
GROUP BY `year`
       , `title`
ORDER BY `title
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5566fc/5)